# Exception in wildfly log CONNECT check.proxyradar.com:80

Tags: jakarta-ee, server, wildfly, wildfly-10, connectionexception

it was appearing a strange exception in log related to chek.proxyradar.com, in my server I'm not using nothing related to proxyradar...
This is exception:

```
2016-12-03 10:38:10,394 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-2) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ CONNECT check.proxyradar.com:80 request {} response {X-Powered-By=[Undertow/1], Server=[WildFly/10]}}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatchesData.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatchesData.java:83)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatches.java:83)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:151)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:39)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$OptionsHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:295)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:90)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$HostRootHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:303)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.NameVirtualHostHandler.handleRequest(NameVirtualHostHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.error.SimpleErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SimpleErrorPageHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.CanonicalPathHandler.handleRequest(CanonicalPathHandler.java:49)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.ChannelUpgradeHandler.handleRequest(ChannelUpgradeHandler.java:158)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.handleRequest(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:95)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisallowedMethodsHandler.handleRequest(DisallowedMethodsHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:243)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:134)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:148)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:92)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:51)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:291)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:286)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.nio.QueuedNioTcpServer$1.run(QueuedNioTcpServer.java:128)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:588)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:468)
```

Any ideas? 
Should I block connections from proxyradar.com via iptables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem with wildfly undertow libraries. It's solved in wildfly 11, but today is an alpha realese, not stable.